# HH:MM:SS:MS Formatting in excel

Tags: excel

I have a lot of data in the form of
"00:00:03:19"
(hh:mm:ss:milliseconds)

I can not do much with it since excel is interpreting the data as text. Under "format cells/custom"

I can not find an appropriate entry for the data.... How can I teach/show excel what kind of data I am processing there?

Comment: Just for the record, the last 2 digits are actually *centiseconds*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only option for Excel to read that properly is to somehow replace the last colon `:` with a decimal point. It's not until Excel *understood* your data as expected that you can think of the appropriate display format.

How are you receiving this data? If you can have all these values aligned in a single column in a csv file for example, by using a good text editor like Notepad++ you could select all the last `:` with ALT + mouse, replace them all at once, and finally load that into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",3)
```

select, Copy, Paste Special, Values then Text to Columns with Tab as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution!
I pasted the timevalues into the A column  and split it via the LEFT,MID RIGHT comands

(eg:00:00:01:21 in A3)

```
A---------------------B-----------------C----------------D---------------E-----------------------F-------- 

00:00:01:21 --     LEFT(A3;2) --    MID(A3;4;2) --  MID(A3;7;2) --  (RIGHT(A3;2)) --    E3+(D3*1000)+(C3*60000)+(B3*3600000)
```